# How to modify sys.stdin.readline() to read all the input data at the same time?

Tags: python, stdin

I am working on the assignment of Data Structure from Coursera - not asking for answer, but I do need to modify the code:

```
def main():
  nodes = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
  tree = []
  for i in range(nodes):
    tree.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
  if IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
    print("CORRECT")
  else:
    print("INCORRECT")
```

so that instead of typing the input data line by line, I can make the program read all of them at the same time, for doing so can save me a lot of time while de-buging.

```
3
1 1 2
2 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
```

How can I achieve that

Comment: How about putting `sys.stdin.readline` into a loop?

Comment: ... which you already do, so I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Not sure how to do what you're asking, but you could instead leave the code as is, put the test input into a file, and launch the program like `python script.py < input.txt` (`sh`/`bash`). In `cmd.exe` I think the equivalent would be `type input.txt | python script.py`.

Comment: Got it, no need to modify the code, simply use command line tools.